# How to add a Primary Key with fluent API - Entity Framework EF 4.x Code First

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, code-first

I need to map some auto generated classes, which I dont want to change for obviouse reasions (it's auto generated!).

So is there a possibility to define a Primary Key with fluent API of the Entity Framework (4.3 in my case)? Handling Attributes as ComplexType leads to DbUpdateExcetion due to NULL values. Adding a Primary Key to the generated classes may be a solution, but not suitable for me, POCOs must stay unchanged. Pleas help! Thanks.

Currently I am ignoring the Attributes because of the...

> ```
> ModelValidationException 
> EntityType 'Attribute' has no key defined.  Define the key for this EntityType.
> EntitySet 'Attributes' is based on type 'Attribute' that has no keys defined.
> ```

here is a shortend sample code:

```
public class Item
{
   public ID {set;get;}
   public Attribute[] Attributes {set;get;}
} 
public class Attribute
{
   public SomeComplexType misc1 {set; get;}
   public SomeComplexType misc2 {set; get;}
}

public class ItemDb : DbContext
{
    public ItemDb(string connection) : base(connection)  {}

    public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
      // currently I am ignoring the Attributes 
        builder.Ignore<Attributes>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [HasKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671266%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) method.

```
builder.Entity<FooBar>().HasKey(...);
```

Comment: only on existing properties as I know

Comment: Yes. Beucase every entity in Entity Framework must have a key property.

Comment: @cincura.net: Hi, it is the property of EF to have primary key for each table? I mean i can't have table without primary key in EF?

Comment: Yes. Every entity needs to have a key. BTW this is a completely different question. Maybe better to ask new, I'll reply there ASAP.